# Star Trek Original series # of encounters with entities having Q like characteristics

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-q

In the Star Trek Original series, what episodes did they encounter entities with Q like characteristics?

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one covered pretty much all the examples that are seen in the canon. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 7):

Restricting ourselves to those who have inexplicable "[godlike](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Powerful_and_godlike_beings)" powers and an incorporeal form, there are a relatively small number of TOS episodes that fit the description. The most obviously comparable (with Q) are the [Organians](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Organian) and [Trelane](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Trelane)

- [Charlie X](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Charlie_X) - Thasians
- [Who Mourns for Adonis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Greek_god) - Apollo
- [Arena](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Arena_(episode)) - The Metrons
- [Errand of Mercy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Errand_of_Mercy_(episode)) -  The Organians
- [Return to Tomorrow](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Return_to_Tomorrow_(episode)) - Sargon
- [The Squire of Gothos](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Squire_of_Gothos_(episode)) - Trelane

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other [excellent answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/115152/84134), I'd like to add the two episodes

- [Day of the Dove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day_of_the_Dove)  - in which an unnamed non corporeal entity forces the crew to fight some Klingons. Displays the ability to manipulate matter and energy
- [And The Children Shall Lead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/And_the_Children_Shall_Lead) - contains the character Gorgon. A non corporeal being with mind control powers.

Neither of these creatures are up there with Q in terms of power, but both appear in non-canon works with Q, in which the creature from Day of the Dove is given the name (*).

Comment: Hmm. I excluded both of these because they're dramatically less powerful than the Q. Certainly not "godlike"

Comment: (*) has got some very high level powers. Including blocking technology, swapping matter about. Perhaps god like a lower g. The Gorgon is a stretch as he's basically a paedophile ghost

Comment: "Non-canon." Sorry.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon no problem. Feel free to edit any of my posts for spellings they are atrocious :)